# ASP.NET Web Forms Control Event Handling vs. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, event-handling

For the following scenario, there seems to be two approaches.  This example is for a Select All checkbox in a GridView header, but I am also wondering if this consideration could be made with other controls (e.g. asp:Button click).  I am also wondering whether this trade-off exists not only in ASP.NET Web Forms Event Handling (vs. JavaScript), but in other innate event handling (vs. JavaScript).

PROBLEM STATEMENT:

In needing to handle when a GridView in an ASP.NET Web Form application, I researched methods to receive notification that the Select All header checkbox was clicked.  At first, I found this solution, which suggested to use JavaScript to handle the header click (and row checkbox clicks):

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <HeaderTemplate>
      <asp:CheckBox ID="checkAll" runat="server" onclick = "checkAll(this);" />
    </HeaderTemplate>
   <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:CheckBox ID="rowCheck" runat="server" onclick = "Check_Click(this)" />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Since I had gotten this far in the application without involving any JavaScript, I looked to see if there was a solution involving only innate event handling, and found:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <HeaderTemplate>
      <asp:CheckBox ID="checkAll" runat="server" OnCheckChanged="checkAll_OnCheckChanged" />
    </HeaderTemplate>
   <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:CheckBox ID="rowCheck" runat="server" OnCheckChanged="rowCheck_OnCheckChanged" />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

While I know I could have done this with JavaScript, I opted for the innate event handling.

The question is, what is the argument for doing this the JavaScript way?  (the latter example here is working nicely).  I am just wondering whether JavaScript is more reliable to receiving notifications that these checkboxes were clicked.

Comment: To do it in Javascript you replace `OnCheckChanged` with `onchange`. It is not more reliable, yet why make a roundtrip to the server if not required? Each checkbox change will kind of reload the whole page due to postback. I would drop *GridView* altogether and go with a modern *jslist*, which you will find plenty by now.

Comment: @Lain I was not aware.  Can't find good documentation for jslist.  Do you have a link?

Comment: There are different table-plugins for Javascript. I am using a deeply customised version of **Slickgrid**, which will not work for you. The ones I remember are [grid.js](https://gridjs.io/), *SlickGrid* and [DataGrid](https://js.devexpress.com/Overview/DataGrid/). However, my knowledge on those is not up to date.